# Need to make slider dynamic using React

Tags: reactjs, slider

I need to make my slider dynamic in order to set my slider to the amount of images in the specified imagePath for about 14 different cases. The cases are just `clickListeners` in which the user is expecting to view more images under a certain category. So there are more images to view if the user clicks on 'editorial-text' div and there are more images for the user to view if they click on 'commercial-text' div. My code works, it's just not assigning the different images (from different `imagePaths`) correctly to the slider. It's always dominated by the `imageHelperGenerator()` function that sets the amount of slide images to 7 as the default, but also my slider is starting at the end and cutting off the images that do show. Here's my jsx code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './css/index.css';
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { SplitText } from "gsap/dist/SplitText";
import {imageHelperGenerator} from "../helpers/imageHelper.js";

gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText);

//this is where it dominates all sliders at the moment, needs to only be default slider when user hasn't clicked anything:

const bgImages = imageHelperGenerator(7);

console.log("Images value", bgImages);

const SliderComponent = () => (
    <main className="slider-container" data-barba-namespace="home-section">
        <div className="slider">
            <div className="slider-inner" id="slider-inner1">
                {
                    bgImages.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="item">
                                <div className="img" id={`bk${index + 1}`}></div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
);


export default function Index() {
    const [showSlider, setShowSlider] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Main Timeline
        var splitTextMain = new SplitText('h1', {type: 'chars'});
        var tl = gsap.timeline();

        tl
            .from(splitTextMain.chars, {duration: 0.5, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.125, ease: 'power1.in'})
            .to(splitTextMain.chars, {duration: 0.20, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.125, ease: 'power3.inOut'}, '+=3');

        var splitTextTitle = new SplitText('h3', {type: 'chars'});
        var titleTimeline = gsap.timeline({delay: 3});

        titleTimeline
            .from(splitTextTitle.chars, {duration: 0.5, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.125, ease: 'power1.in'})
            .to(splitTextTitle.chars, {duration: 0.25, opacity: 1, stagger: .125, ease: 'power3.in'}, '+=3');

        // Slide animation for the hidden container
        gsap.from('.hidden-container', {duration: 3, opacity: 1, ease: 'power3.in', delay: 4});
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('.hidden-container').classList.add('slide-left');
        }, 7000); // Adjust the delay as needed

        var splitTextNav = new SplitText('h4', {type: 'chars'});
        var navTimeline = gsap.timeline({delay: 4});

        navTimeline
            .from(splitTextNav.chars, {duration: 0.5, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.125, ease: 'power1.in'})
            .to(splitTextNav.chars, {duration: 0.25, opacity: 1, stagger: .125, ease: 'power3. in'}, '+=3')

        gsap.from('.nav-container', {duration: 6, opacity: 1, ease: 'power3. in', delay: 8});
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('.nav-container');
        }, 9000); // Adjust the delay as needed

        var splitTextContact = new SplitText('h4', {type: 'chars'});
        var contactTimeline = gsap.timeline();

        contactTimeline
            .from(splitTextContact.chars, {duration: 0.5, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.125, ease: 'power1.in'})
            .to(splitTextContact.chars, {duration: 0.25, opacity: 1, stagger: .125, ease: 'power3.in'}, '+=3');

        // Slide animation for the hidden container
        gsap.from('.contact-container', {duration: 3, opacity: 1, ease: 'power3.in', delay: 4});
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('.contact-container');
        }, 8700); // Adjust the delay as needed

        const dashTimeline = gsap.timeline({delay: 7});

        dashTimeline.from(".first-dash", {duration: 0.7, opacity: 0, ease: "ease-in"});

        dashTimeline.kill();

        const sliderInitializationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')];
            const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
            let sliderWidth;
            let imageWidth;
            let current = 0;
            let target = 0;
            const ease = 0.03;

            window.addEventListener('resize', init);

            // Default behavior when neither link is clicked
            const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

            sliderImages.forEach((img, index) => {
                img.style.backgroundImage = `url(./images/main/${index + 1}.jpeg)`;
            });

            function lerp(start, end, t) {
                return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
            }

            function setTransform(el, transform) {
                el.style.transform = transform;
            }

            function init() {
                sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
                imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length * 2;
                document.body.style.height = `${sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)}px`

                slider.style.opacity = '0';
                slider.style.transform = 'translateY(0) translateX(100%)';
            }

            function animate() {
                current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
                target = window.scrollY;

                // Check if the slider has not started the animation yet
                if (slider.style.opacity === '0') {
                    // Start the fade-in and slide animation
                    slider.style.transition = 'opacity 250ms ease-out, transform 250ms ease-out';
                    slider.style.opacity = '0.8';
                    // Set the initial position to 0
                    current = 0;
                }

                setTransform(slider, `translateX(-${current}px)`);
                animateImages();

                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }


            function animateImages() {
                let ratio = current / imageWidth;
                let intersectionRatioValue;

                images.forEach((image, index) => {
                    intersectionRatioValue = ratio - (index * 0.7);
                    setTransform(image, `translateX(${intersectionRatioValue * 70}px)`);

                    const opacityValue = Math.min(0.8, 1);
                    image.style.opacity = opacityValue;
                });
            }
            init();
            animate();
        }, 9000);
        return () => clearTimeout(sliderInitializationTimeout);
    }, []), useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setShowSlider(true);
        }, 8500);
        // Clean up the timeout when the component unmounts
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, [])

    function bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider(bookId, clickHandler) {
        const bookCover = document.getElementById(bookId);
        if (bookCover) {
            bookCover.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        }
    }

    //This needs to be called only when the user clicks on the bookCover img.

    function bookCoverClick(bookId, imagesPath, totalImages, redirectFunction) {
        const bookCover = document.getElementById(bookId);
        const fadeOutDuration = 0.8 * 1000; // Convert seconds to milliseconds
        const redirectDelay = 800; // milliseconds

        bookCover.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Sets the slider length to the specified totalImages and update images
            updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages);

            const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
            const initialPosition = gsap.getProperty(slider, 'xPercent');

            // Smooth fade-out with a specified duration
            bookCover.style.transition = `opacity ${fadeOutDuration / 1000}s ease`;
            bookCover.style.opacity = '0';
            // Slides out the slider to the right by 70%
            gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition + 150, ease: "power3.inOut" });

            // Redirects to the new page after a specified delay
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Call the provided function for redirection
                if (typeof redirectFunction === 'function') {
                    redirectFunction();
                }
                // Slide back in the slider from the updated position
                gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition, ease: "power3.inOut" });
            }, redirectDelay);
        });
    }

    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk1", () => slideImages("./images/bookOne"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk2", () => slideImages("./images/bookTwo"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk3", () => slideImages("./images/bookThree"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk4", () => slideImages("./images/bookFour"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk5", () => slideImages("./images.bookFive"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk6", () => slideImages("./images/bookSix"));
    bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider("bk7", () => slideImages("./images/bookSeven"));

    function setupBookCoverClickHandlers() {
        // Assuming you have elements with the IDs "editorial-text" and "commercial-text"
        const editorialText = document.getElementById("editorial-text");
        const commercialText = document.getElementById("commercial-text");

        if (editorialText) {
            editorialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log("in editorial text listener");
                // User clicks on "editorial-text"
                bookCoverClick("bk1", './images/bookOne', 8);
                bookCoverClick("bk2", './images/bookTwo', 9);
                bookCoverClick("bk3", './images/bookThree', 10);
                bookCoverClick("bk4", './images/bookFour', 4);
                bookCoverClick("bk5", "./images/bookFive", 8);
                bookCoverClick("bk6", "./images/bookSix", 10);
                bookCoverClick("bk7", "./images/bookSeven", 6);
            });
        }
        if (commercialText) {
            commercialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log("in commercial text listener");
                // User clicks on "commercial-text"
                bookCoverClick("bk1", './images/commmain/gilt', 3);
                bookCoverClick("bk2", './images/commmain/giltapparel', 4);
                bookCoverClick("bk3", './images/commmain/saksfifth', 1);
                bookCoverClick("bk4", './images/commmain/lofficielusa', 12);
                bookCoverClick("bk5", './images/commmain/voguearabia', 13);
                bookCoverClick("bk6", './images/commmain/harpersbazaartaiwan', 6);
                bookCoverClick("bk7", './images/commmain/commonsandsense', 9);
            });
        }
    }
    setupBookCoverClickHandlers();

    function slideImages(imagesPath, totalImages) {
        const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".img")];
        const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

        const timeline = gsap.timeline();

        const initialPosition = gsap.getProperty(slider, 'xPercent');

        timeline
            // Slide out the slider to the right by 70%
            .to(slider, {duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition + 150, ease: "power3.inOut"})
            // Change images to the specified path
            .call(() => updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages))
            // Slide back in the slider from the updated position
            .to(slider, {duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition, ease: "power3.inOut"});
    }

    function updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages) {
        const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".img")];

        images.forEach((img, index) => {
            img.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagesPath}/${index + 1}.jpeg)`;
        });

        // Calculate the total width of the slider based on the number of images
        const sliderWidth = totalImages * 100; // Assuming each image takes 100% width
        const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
        slider.style.width = `${sliderWidth}vw`;
    }


    function editorialSlide() {
        slideImages('./images/main');
    }

    function commercialSlide() {
        slideImages('./images/commmain');
    }


    return (
        <>
            <div className="left-panel"></div>
            <div className="name"><h1><strong>ALEX </strong>MAGOBA<strong></strong></h1></div>
            <div className="hidden-container" style={{ opacity: 1}}>
                <h3><strong>STYLIST</strong></h3>
                <h3><strong>CREATIVE DIRECTOR</strong></h3>
                <h3><strong>STORYTELLER</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div className="contact-container">
                <h4><strong>CONTACT:</strong></h4>
                <hr className="first-dash"/>
                <h4><a href={`mailto:magoba5173@gmail.com`}>info@alexmagoba.com</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div className="nav-container">
                <h4>
                    <strong>
                        <p id="editorial-text" onClick={editorialSlide}>Editorial</p>
                    </strong>
                </h4>

                <h4>
                    <strong>
                        <p id="commercial-text" onClick={commercialSlide}>Commercial</p>
                    </strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
            {showSlider && <SliderComponent />}
        </>
    );
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it at all possible to trim this down to a *minimal* reproducible example?  This is a ton of code for anyone to wade through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey:) You have a constant bgImages that is initialized with imageHelperGenerator(7), which sets the default number of images for the slider.
This default value might be interfering with the dynamic image loading for different categories.

The slider is initialized with default images and settings in the useEffect hook.
Instead, you should initialize the slider and images dynamically based on user interactions.

The updateImages function is responsible for updating the background images of the slider. It should handle the dynamic loading of images based on the provided imagesPath and totalImages.

The click event listeners for book covers (bookCoverClickForDefaultSlider) should be removed, as you want to attach dynamic event listeners based on user interactions.

And I would combine the bookCoverClick and SlideImages functions to avoid duplication.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './css/index.css';
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { SplitText } from "gsap/dist/SplitText";
import { imageHelperGenerator } from "../helpers/imageHelper.js";

gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText);

const SliderComponent = () => (
  <main className="slider-container" data-barba-namespace="home-section">
    <div className="slider">
      <div className="slider-inner" id="slider-inner1">
        {/* Render slider items dynamically */}
        {
          [...Array(7)].map((_, index) => (
            <div className="item" key={index}>
              <div className="img" id={`bk${index + 1}`} style={{ 
                backgroundImage: `url(./images/main/${index + 1}.jpeg)` }}> 
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
);

export default function Index() {
  const [showSlider, setShowSlider] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Your code useEffect

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSlider(true);
    }, 8500);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, []);

  function handleCategoryClick(imagesPath, totalImages) {
    const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    const initialPosition = gsap.getProperty(slider, 'xPercent');

    gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition + 150, ease: 
        "power3.inOut" });

    updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages);

    gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition, ease: 
        "power3.inOut" });
      }

  function updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages) {
    const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".img")];

    images.forEach((img, index) => {
      img.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagesPath}/${index + 1}.jpeg)`;
    });

    const sliderWidth = totalImages * 100;
    const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    slider.style.width = `${sliderWidth}vw`;
  }

  function setupBookCoverClickHandlers() {
    const editorialText = document.getElementById("editorial-text");
    const commercialText = document.getElementById("commercial-text");

    if (editorialText) {
      editorialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handleCategoryClick('./images/main', 7);
      });
    }
    if (commercialText) {
      commercialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handleCategoryClick('./images/commmain', 7);
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setupBookCoverClickHandlers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Your structure */}
      {showSlider && <SliderComponent />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Addition to your comment
1)You need to change SliderComponent: Add a state variable to store the current category (for example, currentCategory). Pass currentCategory as a SliderComponent property

```
const SliderComponent = ({ currentCategory }) => (
  <main className="slider-container" data-barba-namespace="home-section">
    <div className="slider">
      <div className="slider-inner" id="slider-inner1">
        {[...Array(7)].map((_, index) => (
          <div className="item" key={index}>
            <div
              className="img"
              id={`bk${index + 1}`}
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${currentCategory}/${index + 1}.jpeg)`,
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

2)Change index component: Add a state variable to hold the current category (for example, currentCategory). Modify the handleCategoryClick function to update the currentCategory state.

```
export default function Index() {
  const [showSlider, setShowSlider] = useState(false);
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState('./images/main');

  // ... other code ...

  function handleCategoryClick(imagesPath, totalImages) {
    setCurrentCategory(imagesPath);
    const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    const initialPosition = gsap.getProperty(slider, 'xPercent');

    gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition + 150, ease: "power3.inOut" });

    updateImages(imagesPath, totalImages);

    gsap.to(slider, { duration: 1, xPercent: initialPosition, ease: "power3.inOut" });
  }

  // ... other code ...

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... other code ... */}
      {showSlider && <SliderComponent currentCategory={currentCategory} 
    </>
  );
}
```

Set up image paths in your click handlers: Update the paths in the editorialText and CommercialText click handlers to match the new structure.

```
function setupBookCoverClickHandlers() {
  const editorialText = document.getElementById("editorial-text");
  const commercialText = document.getElementById("commercial-text");

  if (editorialText) {
    editorialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
      handleCategoryClick('./images/main', 7);
    });
  }
  if (commercialText) {
    commercialText.addEventListener("click", () => {
      handleCategoryClick('./images/commmain', 7);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful Rose, thank you! Just having trouble trying to sort through the following case: if the user clicks on editorial-text, and the slider loads all the images under editorial, then the user clicks on the first div (bk1) from that slider, the slider should then load images from ./images/bookOne. Can you break down how I'd implement that please?

Comment: I added to the answer taking into account your comment :)